# In the DOM model/JavaScript , Is there a difference between a a text box and the value entered into it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, firebug

I know this might be  really baby-question.. but it's confusing me.  If I'm looking at a page(which is an SSRS- generated webpage, i.e ReportViewer) in Firebug, like so:

[image]

So I want to get the ID of the actual input-box there , and the label coming up says `_value`  - does this mean I'm not getting the input-box ID? How would I obtain that(just the input text-box)?

thanks!

Comment: Are you using JSF or ASP.NET? The HTML IDs those frameworks emit is a different if related beast to the component ID you use.

Comment: Yes, it's ASP.NET  , with SSRS report-viewer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ID for that input is `MainContent_rptCompletes_ctl00_ctl03_txtValue` (thanks to ASP.NET webforms).

Answer (score 2):

You can retrieve the `TextBox` `ID` using `TextBox.ClientID`. If you want to ensure that the `TextBox` has the same `ClientID` as it's `ID`, then set the `ClientIDMode` to `Static`.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="BoxID" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static">
</asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: Ah, I must mention that this is an SSRS-generated web-page

Comment: @Adel SSRS is based on ASP.NET WebForms, so it's the same thing.